# Changing current user password in pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Am trying to change the password of the currently logged in user in pyramid-pylons application. I have already implemented the authentiation and authorisation policy and even imported authenticated_userid but still unable to return the current user.

Tried to log but nothing is even returned to the console. Any help will be appreciated

Here is my code snippet with the get_current user_function

```
def get_current_user(request):
    log.debug('un-auth uid: ' + unauthenticated_userid(request))
    user = DBSession.query(User).filter(
    User.username ==  authenticated_userid(request)
    ).first()
    log.debug('user: ' + str(owner.__dict__))
    return owner
```

Comment: Try breaking your code with `pdb.set_trace()` and see that you're getting the expected results after each line of code. Additionally, check to make sure your console output level is "INFO" or "DEBUG" for `[logger_sqlalchemy]` in your development.ini file, so that you may see what's going on with your SQLAlchemy queries.

Comment: @Raj console ouput level is info  but still not able to see anyting in the console

Comment: And what does `pdb.set_trace()` tell you each step of the way?

Comment: What does your login routine look like?  Is it based on the Pyramid tutorials on the project site?  Your log.debug statements above - what is their output?

Comment: Its based on pyramid tutorial on the site (Group Level  Security). The log .debug statements don't return anything. Thats what puzzles me yet the group level authentication works perfectly

Comment: -> log.debug('auth uid: ' + str(user))
(Pdb) 2015-01-29 13:16:45,028 DEBUG [beatstore.views][Dummy-3] auth uid: None